# Using Ansible playbook to install Oracle12c

Tags: ansible, oracle12c

I developed a ansible playbook to automate the installation of Oracle 12c Release 2 on CentOS7 and I get a full install. However I cannot start the database instance with `startup`, I generate the `dbca.rsp` from a template using the ansible vars in the template to generate it with the command:

`- name: create database
 command: '{{ oracle_home }}/bin/dbca -silent -createDatabase -sid {{ oracle_sid }} -templateName General_Purpose.dbc -responseFile {{ installation_folder }}/dbca.rsp'`

The expected result would be the normal installation and the creation of the file `initSID.ora` but I'm only getting the `init.ora` file which as no SID attached to it with out being in it's core and thus I'm not able to start a instance of the database.

When I use `sqlplus / as sysdba` to connect as the SYSDBA to have privileges ans use `startup` or `STARTUP PFILE ='/oracle/app/oracle/product/12201/dbhome_1/dbs/init.ora';`

I get the errors:

`ORA-01261: Parameter db_recovery_file_dest destination string cannot be translated
ORA-01262: Stat failed on a file destination directory
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory`

Creating a new PFILE or SPFILE will return the same errors

I suspect is the `dbca.rsp` that is not generating a good startup file since the others response files are generating the install setup (`db_install.rsp`) and the linstener (`netca.rsp`) and the data on those files are being fullfiled correctly.

Note that the templates that I'm using are extracted from a clean and fresh install from oracle12c Release 2 where only the variables contain as values of the variables from the playbook itself like the SID, install location, inventory location, ...

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: I did. I had to generate a new dbca.rsp. Mine had a few incomplete paths and names and thus creating incorrect init.ora files and no pfiles. I made a manual installation and saving the response file, uninstall and silently install it with the new response file. Then I made a template for it with ansible variables and it's now installing ok.

Comment: The dbca.rsp was indeed the issue. Thank you!